# Print long long via fast i/o

Tags: c++, c

The following code is used to print an `int`. How can I modify it to print a `long long int`? Please explain.

For `pc`, read [`putchar_unlocked`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar_unlocked)

```
inline void writeInt (int n)
{
    int N = n, rev, count = 0;
    rev = N;
    if (N == 0) { pc('0'); pc('\n'); return ;}
    while ((rev % 10) == 0) { count++; rev /= 10;}
    rev = 0;
    while (N != 0) { rev = (rev<<3) + (rev<<1) + N % 10; N /= 10;}
    while (rev != 0) { pc(rev % 10 + '0'); rev /= 10;}
    while (count--) pc('0');
    pc('\n');
    return ;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing specific about int in the code. Just replace both occurrences of "int" by "long long int", and you're done.

(I find the "optimization" of *10 via shift and add quite ridiculous with all the divisions that remain. Any decent C compiler will do that (and much more) automatically. And don't forget to profile this "fast" version against the stdlib routine, to be sure it really was worth the effort).

Comment: The modulo's aren't cheap either. I'd use unrolled loops: `if ((rev % 100000000)==0) { count +=8; rev /= 100000000; } if ((rev % 10000)==0) { count +=4; rev /= 10000; } // etc` but naively done that would introduce a size assumption.

Answer (score 5):

This code is a lit more complex than it needs to be:

```
inline void writeLongLong (long long n)
{
    char buffer[sizeof(n) * 8 * 3 / 10 + 3];  // 3 digits per 10 bits + two extra and space for terminating zero. 
    int index = sizeof(buffer)-1;
    int end = index;
    buffer[index--] = 0;
    do {
       buffer[index--] = (n % 10) + '0';
       n /= 10;
    } while(n);
    puts(&buffer[index+1]);
}
```

This does the same job, with about half as many divide/modulo operations and at least I can follow it better. Note that stdio/stdlib functions are probably better than this, and this function does not cope with negative numbers (neither does the one posted above).